# JavaScript Detect which link number has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I need to return the number that the link is on the page, of the links to that specific page, in order to use this in Google Analytics / Tag Manager event tracking.

i.e. There are 4 links on a page to another website, all have the same code and text, if the third of these links is clicked I want the code to return the number 3.

I'm thinking I can find the element that was clicked, count how many links there are on the page for it, then count how many through that total this one is. But I can't piece it together... Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Taplar indeed.